# Создать столбец,вычитающий предыдущее значение

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть таблица по типу:

| id | target |
| --- | --- |
| 001 | 0 |
| 001 | 1 |
| 001 | 1 |

необходимо создать столбец с увеличивающимся счетчиком, начиная с отрицательных значений. При первом значении target=1, значение будет 0 и так далее. По типу:

| id | target | res |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 0 | -1 |
| 001 | 1 | 0 |
| 001 | 1 | 1 |

при наступлении target = 1, далее других значений в таргете не будет

Есть идея по каждому id посчитать сумму по столбцу target и постепенно вычитать 1 (предварительно перевернув). Должно получиться s = s, s1 = s - 1, s2 = s1 - 1 и т.п. Но не знаю как реализовать.

Использую microsoft sql-server 2017

Answer (score 1):

Если нужен инкремент в зависимости от содержимого другого поля, то нужно делать триггер на вставку новой строки.
Есть ответ [тут (на английском)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10769780/sql-server-dependent-identity-is-there-such-a-thing)

```
CREATE TRIGGER ResIncrement
   ON  myTable
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    update myTable
    set 
        res = (select coalesce(MAX(target), 0) - 1 
                      from myTable r where r.id = inserted.id )
    from
        inserted where myTable.Id = inserted.Id

END
```

*Использование триггеров не рекомендуются от слова совсем.  Только в крайнем случае, если нет доступа к коду работающему с БД.*

Answer (score 0):

Можно при создании таблицы назначить автоинкремент и его стартовое значение для столбца:

```
CREATE TABLE myTable
(
 id int,
 target int,
 res int IDENTITY(-1,1) -- начинаем с -1, с шагом 1
)
```

Либо добавить в существующей

```
ALTER TABLE myTable ALTER COLUMN res INT IDENTITY (-1, 1);
```

Comment: Если будет множество id с разным количеством строк по одному id, работать же не будет